# What libraries does eclipse need in build path for Hibernate?

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate

I'm learning Hibernate and am following an online tutorial on integrating it with Eclipse. I have installed the JBoss plugin with Hibernate into Eclipse Luna 4.4. and verified I have Hibernate available. The next step is to configure the build path for my new Java project and include the "necessary" Hibernate libraries...no information given on how to do that. How does one go about identifying the required jar files? I see several folders under my eclipse plugins directory that contain jboss or hibernate in the folder name, and underneath these folders do exist jar files, but I would think that there must be an easier way than plodding through all these directories and adding any jar file that looks like it's related to Hibernate or JBoss. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try this - http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-install-hibernate-tools-in-eclipse-ide/ or this https://kaanmutlu.wordpress.com/2011/07/30/hibernate-installationsetup-on-eclipse-ide/

Comment: Thanks....the wordpress link is what I needed.